# Does casting a spell with a longer casting time end a spell that you were previously maintaining concentration on?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, concentration

From D&D Player's Basic Rules v0.3, p79:

> #### Longer Casting Times
>
> Certain spells (including spells cast as rituals) require more time to cast: minutes or even hours. When you cast a spell with a casting time longer than a single action or reaction, you must spend your action each turn casting the spell, and **you must maintain your concentration while you do so** (see “Concentration” below). If your concentration is broken, the spell fails, but you don’t expend a spell slot. If you want to try casting the spell again, you must start over.

Does casting a spell with a longer casting time force the caster to end an active Concentration-duration spell?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes.

You cannot concentrate on two spells at once, thus casting the second spell, ends the first. Because casting a spell that requires concentration ends the first, and the spell requires concentration for the *duration of the casting effort*, it's a spell that requires concentration.